# Firebird, select gives token unknown

Tags: select, firebird

I have a Firebird database with a table `foo` that have a field called `WHEN`. Is there a way to perform a query using the field name in SELECT?

This works:

```
SELECT * FROM foo;
```

This not:

```
SELECT WHEN FROM foo;
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 1, column 18
WHEN
```

Any hints?

Comment: Ok.. i think this is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800841/using-reserved-word-timestamp-as-a-field-name-firebird-2-5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The token `WHEN` is a reserved word, and can't be used as a column name without explicitly quoting it. Either rename the column, or quote it:

```
select "WHEN" from foo
```

Be aware that quoting names makes them case sensitive. Unquoted object names in Firebird are case insensitive, but stored in uppercase.